# Multi-value ComboBox not saving data in linked table (Form/Query)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I currently have a Multi-Value field based on a list of e-mail address, in MS Access 2016. Both the destination table, and the table where the list is pulled, are linked tables. The ComboBox doesn't work for either Queries or Forms when the destination table is a Linked Table. It works for regular Table.

I wish to save multiple e-mail address in this field, without having to use a secondary table (this would be a better design, but would make building forms a complete nightmare, both for me and the users). The inner data storage is a CSV-like format with a ";" delimiter, automatically handled my Access.

To answer obvious questions :

- I will not use a separate table as "Good Design" suggests, to not kill UX and database simplicity.
- There is no VBA involved at all anywhere in that selection form.

Question : What am I missing, and what can I do to make this work in an MS Access Form with a linked table?

Here it what the selection tool from Access Form looks like :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being :

- Unlink the table from the front-end
- Re-link it

It seems like any complex field (Multi-Value, Calculated, Attachment) requires a re-linking of the table.